# Dropbox API oAuth2 Acces Token

Tags: php, html, api, dropbox, oauth-2.0

I have a national and international travel agency, and i have a db with so many passengers and important information. So I want to do a backup of that db everytime I save a new one.
So my idea was upload the backup file to my Dropbox account when I click on save button.
I could make backup load successfully, but the problem is that whenever I want to upload a new backup, ask me a token code acces when used, expires.
What I need is to skip this step or put automatically the token acces code without redirect.

Is there any solution ? So many thanks for your time.
Greetings!

Here is my code of my backup.php:

```html
<?php

$fecha = date("d") . "-" . date("m") . "-" . date("Y");
exec('mysqldump --user=taiyovia_admin --password=50095009 --host=localhost --databases taiyovia_pax taiyovia_usuario taiyovia_rooming > backup/'.$fecha.'.sql');

# Include the Dropbox SDK libraries
require_once "Dropbox/lib/Dropbox/autoload.php";
use \Dropbox as dbx;

$json = "app.json";

$appInfo = dbx\AppInfo::loadFromJsonFile($json);
$webAuth = new dbx\WebAuthNoRedirect($appInfo, "PHP-Example/1.0");

$authorizeUrl = $webAuth->start();

echo "1. Go to: " . $authorizeUrl . "\n";
echo "2. Click \"Allow\" (you might have to log in first).\n";
echo "3. Copy the authorization code.\n";
$authCode ="HERE IS WHERE I PUT THE ACCES TOKEN CODE TO UPLOAD THE FILE";

list($accessToken, $dropboxUserId) = $webAuth->finish($authCode);
print "Access Token: " . $accessToken . "\n";

$dbxClient = new dbx\Client($accessToken, "PHP-Example/1.0");
$accountInfo = $dbxClient->getAccountInfo();

print_r($accountInfo);

$f = fopen("backup/".$fecha.".sql", "rb");
$result = $dbxClient->uploadFile("/".$fecha.".sql", dbx\WriteMode::add(), $f);
fclose($f);
print_r($result);

$folderMetadata = $dbxClient->getMetadataWithChildren("/");
print_r($folderMetadata);

$f = fopen("backup/".$fecha.".sql", "w+b");
$fileMetadata = $dbxClient->getFile("/".$fecha.".sql", $f);
fclose($f);
print_r($fileMetadata);
```

Comment: Are you sure you want the backup on dropbox ? a better method would be to create database replication on mysql.

Comment: Also you don't need to backup data on every query, you can run a cron job to do that task for you every hour or so. Database backup on every insert query is impractical

Comment: The `$accessToken` can be re-used, so you can use some form of data persistence (e.g., save it in a file on disk or in a database) to store and retrieve the access token on subsequent runs, without going through the `$webAuth->start()` flow each time.